# Return highest value in each row into 1 and make the rest of the numbers in row 0

Tags: r, function, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
head(Y_hat)
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
40  0.8316621 0.7593911 0.7446870
56  0.8429158 0.6935900 0.7660440
85  0.8405038 0.6874243 0.7406380
134 0.7269549 0.7584314 0.7089962
30  0.7358268 0.6745820 0.6879305
131 0.7475585 0.7617574 0.7782455
```

I would like to write a function to convert each row into 0 and 1. The highest value in each row would be 1, and the other two values would be 0. For example, row 40 would return (1 0 0). How would I do this?

Comment: `mat == apply(mat, 1, max)`

Comment: `t(apply(Y_hat, 1, function(x) as.numeric(x == max(x))))`

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can compare by taking the `max` of each row with `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
+(m1==rowMaxs(m1))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#40     1    0    0
#56     1    0    0
#85     1    0    0
#134    0    1    0
#30     1    0    0
#131    0    0    1
```

---

Or a `base R` option is to the max values per rows via row/column indexing (`max.col`) and then compare

```
+(m1==m1[cbind(1:nrow(m1), max.col(m1))])
```